# Concentration made by a small thing

Tags: classical-mechanics

there is a source of particle(a piece of food) that is way bigger than particles its made of and way smaller than the container containing it(a 3D space (Petri dish filled with water) but what is important is just a cross section seen from top). A particle(bacteria) that can measure concentration (of food particles dissolve in medium) around it and moves through medium. and change direction as concentration changes while it moves and correct its way toward source.
this is what happens in [reality (this shows it, no need to read through the pictures show the idea specially the first one)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemotaxis)

[image](http://www.mit.edu/~kardar/teaching/projects/chemotaxis(AndreaSchmidt)/finding_food.htm)

i don't know if concentration of specific (x,y) changes over time, but i guess its constant?

i'm simulation it with computer programming and the problem i have is the concentration at given(x,y)(there is a z but i assume it moves on a plane that have the source and detector on it), how should it be to be physically correct?

c∝1/r

c∝1/r^2

c∝1/(abs(r)+k) k is positive constant

c∝1/(r^2+k)

....

or any other relation?

(sorry couldn't find the relevant tag)

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. What happens to the particles that are produced? Are they fired away form the source at constant velocity, or do the diffuse from where they started? Try to be as specific as you can. Also, try to TeX up your equations.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it should fall as $1/r$ in two dimensions. Consider a thin shell with radius $r$ around the particle source. Then as time passes, the number of particles inside the shell will be always the same. But the particles which pass through the shell go further into a bigger shell. So, if the particles move with constant speed, there is always the same number of them in any shell of given thickness, so the density falls as the shell area grows. But in two dimensions the shell area grows linearly with the radius, thus the concentration goes like $1/r$.

Comment: what you say seems right to me but is there difference in 2D and 3D? wouldn't concentration(x,y)=concentration(x,y,z)?

Comment: No, in 3D the shell is quadratic in $r$, so the concentration goes like $1/r^2$.

Comment: i understand why its 1/r^2 in 3d and 1/r in 2d, so what if we have a 3D space and get a 2D cross section of it? i guess as you said in this case it should be 1/r^2 because the movement of particles is actually in 3d, am i right?

Comment: If the particles diffuse in all three directions, yes, the concentration will go like $1/r^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with $N$ particles of mass $m$ all at the origin (we ignore the Pauli Exclusion Principle here) of a $d-$dimensional space, what will the distribution of particles look like at some future time $t$?

The initial density can be modeled with a delta funtion:
$$
\rho({\bf r},t=0) = Nm\delta({\bf r})
$$
If the underlying particles are diffusing due to Brownian Motion, then their underlying dynamics obey a [Langevin equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation). Their density (more precisely the probability distribution of a single particle times $Nm$) will obey a [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) which is basically the diffusion equation:

$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = D\nabla^2\rho
$$
where $D$ is the diffusion constant that depends on the fluid the particles are immersed in as well as the structure of the particles themselves.
The solution to this equation with the given initial distribution is:
$$
\rho({\bf r},t) = \frac{Nm}{(4\pi D t)^{d/2}}e^{-\frac{r^2}{4Dt}}
$$
We see that the concentration of particles is a Gaussian that spreads over time. In the limit $t\rightarrow\infty$, the distribution will be uniform over all of space.

Here is a nice presentation on the diffusion equation if you want to know more: [Diffusion Equation](https://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d30345d/courses/engs43/DiffusionEquation.pdf)

Comment: thanks for your very good answer but as t->∞ concentration will become 0 on every point i guess because  you assumed the particles number are limited, in my case i guess there should be some sort of equilibrium, should i take a specific t so i can have a good approximation?

Comment: If you have an infinite volume, then even if you have an infinite number of particles then the density can drop down to $0$. The key is to take the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$ and $V\rightarrow\infty$ while holding $N/V$ fixed. You'll encounter this when you start taking more advanced courses in statistical mechanics. 

What does it mean to pick a single time? You're basically freezing all the particles where they are. This is a reasonable assumption if you are modelling a detector that moves much faster than the speed of sound in the medium. Does your detector move that fast?

Comment: let me screenshot your answer because its too good to miss and ill edit my question